# tornado use AsyncHTTPClient and gen to request a url, use raise gen.Return gets Exceptions

Tags: python, tornado

I'm new to tornado, so I follow the guide of tornado to practice, when I come to use Coroutines, the example says:
    from tornado import gen

```
@gen.coroutine
def fetch_coroutine(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http_client.fetch(url)
    # In Python versions prior to 3.3, returning a value from
    # a generator is not allowed and you must use
    #   raise gen.Return(response.body)
    # instead.
    return response.body
```

when I run this test, it's raise SyntaxError **'return' with argument inside generator**, so I uncomment the advice,like this:
    import tornado.httpserver
    import tornado.ioloop
    import tornado.options
    import tornado.web

```
from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)
from tornado import gen
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

@gen.coroutine
def fetch_coroutine(url):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield http_client.fetch(url)
    #return response.body
    raise gen.Return(response.body)

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")
        data = fetch_coroutine(url = "http://www.baidu.com")
        self.write(data)
        print data


def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

but it raise exception like this:

```
[E 140925 17:35:53 web:1407] Uncaught exception GET / (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', headers={'Accept-Language': 'zh-TW,zh;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,en;q=0.4', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'Host': 'localhost:8888', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0', 'If-None-Match': '"e02aa1b106d5c7c6a98def2b13005d5b84fd8dc8"'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-4.0.2-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1332, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "helloworld.py", line 39, in get
        self.write(data)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-4.0.2-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/tornado/web.py", line 656, in write
        raise TypeError("write() only accepts bytes, unicode, and dict objects")
    TypeError: write() only accepts bytes, unicode, and dict objects
[E 140925 17:35:53 web:1811] 500 GET / (::1) 3.94ms
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation has a very [similar example](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#module-tornado.gen):

```
class GenAsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield http_client.fetch("http://example.com")
        do_something_with_response(response)
        self.render("template.html")
```

In summary:

- In python 2.x you can't return something inside block, decorated with `@gen.coroutine`, only single `return` is allowed
- In python 2.x, if you need to return something inside @gen.coroutine block, then use `raise gen.Return`, as you correctly understand
- You don't need to return anything in `get` method to respond some data to client. You need to `write` something (in example above it is done by calling [`self.render`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=render#tornado.web.RequestHandler.render)) for it.

So, replace this code

```
        do_something_with_response(response)
        self.render("template.html")
```

with this:

```
        self.write(response.body)
        self.finish()
```

[`self.finish()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html?highlight=finish#tornado.web.RequestHandler.finish) will finish response, ending the HTTP request. It is called automatically in `self.render` method.

**Final request handler**:

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.web import RequestHandler
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient


class GenAsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield http_client.fetch("http://google.com")
        self.write(response.body)
        self.finish()
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I follow your advice, but I get nothing in browser, so, can you write a simple example, include a template.html, and you can requests anyone website, and show in the browser? thank you !